# pandas groupby: generate 0 when an event does not occur

Tags: python, pandas, list, pandas-groupby

Given a dataframe, I am grouping 'titles' according to their 'vals'.

```
titles=['MR.', 'MRS.', 'MR.', 'MR.', 'MRS.', 'MR.', 'MISS.', 'MR.', 'MRS.', 'MR.', 'MR.', 'MR.', 'MRS.', 'MR.',
    'MRS.', 'MRS.', 'MR.', 'MR.', 'MISS.', 'MRS.', 'MR.', 'MASTER.', 'MRS.', 'MR.', 'MRS.', 'MR.', 'MISS.', 
    'MR.', 'MR.', 'MR.', 'MR.', 'MR.', 'MRS.', 'MRS.', 'MR.', 'MR.', 'MISS.', 'MISS.', 'MR.', 'MR.', 'MR.', 
    'MR.', 'MR.', 'MRS.', 'MRS.', 'MR.', 'MR.', 'MR.', 'MRS.', 'MRS.', 'MR.', 'MR.', 'MISS.', 'MISS.', 'MR.',
    'MASTER.', 'MR.', 'MR.', 'MR.', 'MISS.', 'MR.', 'MR.', 'MR.', 'MISS.', 'MASTER.', 'MRS.', 'MISS.', 'MR.', 
    'MR.', 'MRS.', 'MR.', 'MISS.', 'MR.', 'MISS.', 'MR.', 'MR.', 'MRS.', 'MR.', 'MASTER.', 'DON.']


vals=[1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,
     0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0]

d = {'titles': []}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['titles']=titles
df['vals']=vals


print(df.groupby([df['vals'] ]['titles'].value_counts())


print(df.groupby([df['vals'] ]['titles'].value_counts().values.tolist())
```

When I print the last line after converting it to list
the output I obtain is the following:

```
[19, 13, 9, 2, 1, 26, 5, 3, 2]
```

but I would like to obtain:

```
[19, 13, 9, 2, 1]
[26, 5, 3, 2]
```

the second list has 4 items instead of 5, and that is because df['titles]='DON.' never corresponds to 1 on the 'vals' column. How do make sure that such instances will be replaced with the value 0 instead of no value at all ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can use:

```
df.groupby('vals')['titles'].value_counts().unstack().fillna(0).values
```

Output:

```
[[ 1.  2.  9. 19. 13.]
 [ 0.  2.  3. 26.  5.]]
```

Comment: this generates an error: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: Can you please post the error in comments. Works fine for me

Comment: <>:17: SyntaxWarning: list indices must be integers or slices, not str; perhaps you missed a comma?
  group_titles_vals=df.groupby(([df['vals'] ])['titles'].value_counts())
 ------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-373-edb929862fcf> in <module>
     15 df['vals']=vals
     16 
---> 17 group_titles_vals=df.groupby(([df['vals'] ])['titles'].value_counts())
     19 #print(df.groupby([df['vals'] ])['titles'].value_counts()).unstack(fillna(0)).stack()
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: I think you are using one extra `()` here. This should work: `group_titles_vals=df.groupby([df['vals'] ])['titles'].value_counts()`

Comment: one more question: how would be possible to derive a list with titles corresponding to the entries of both lists? The outcome should be ['DON.', 'MASTER.','MISS.','MR.','MRS.']

Comment: try `.to_dict('index')` instead of `.values` at the end

Comment: Or remove `.values` at the end and add `data = [df.columns, df.values]` to next line. Which will give youa list of lists with columns headers in first index and actual data in second index.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
>>> df.groupby('vals')['titles'].agg(lambda x: list(x.value_counts())).tolist()
[[19, 13, 9, 2, 1], [26, 5, 3, 2]]
```

Or

```
>>> df.groupby('vals')['titles'].value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0).values

[[1, 2, 9, 19, 13], [0, 2, 3, 26, 5]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension:

```
print([i.value_counts().tolist() for _, i in df.groupby("vals")['titles']])

# [[19, 13, 9, 2, 1], [26, 5, 3, 2]]
```

For your 2nd question you can use `pd.crosstab`:

```
print (pd.crosstab(df["vals"], df["titles"]))

titles  DON.  MASTER.  MISS.  MR.  MRS.
vals                                   
0          1        2      9   19    13
1          0        2      3   26     5
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting from your command, you could use a small list comprehension:

```
# your previous command
counts = df.groupby(df['vals'])['titles'].value_counts()

# list by group
[s.values.tolist() for _,s in counts.groupby(level=0)]
```

output:

```
[[19, 13,  9,  2,  1], [26,  5,  3,  2]]
```

#### getting missing values filled with zero

```
counts = df.groupby(df['vals'])['titles'].value_counts()

list(counts.unstack(fill_value=0).T.to_dict('list').values())
```

output:

```
[[1, 2, 9, 19, 13], [0, 2, 3, 26, 5]]
```